# Any two abelian group of order 8 must be isomorphic

Tags: abelian-groups, graph-isomorphism

TRUE/FALSE :Any two abelian group of order 8 must be isomorphic

SOLUTION: True

The problem of finding all abelian groups of order 8 is impossible to solve, because there are infinitely many possibilities. But if we ask for a list of abelian groups of order 8 that comes with a guarantee that any possible abelian group of order 8 must be isomorphic to one of the groups on the list Z8,     Z4 × Z2,     Z2 × Z2 × Z2.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_8$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: Why do you say that the set of all abelian groups of orther $8$ is infinite?

Comment: @mfl The "set" of all abelian groups of order $8$ is not defined, because the elements of the group can be anything with the structure of a group added on top. The number of isomorphism classes of such groups is finite.

Comment: @MarkBennet You are right, I meant to say modulo isomorphisms.

Comment: @mfl: but the OP did not specify "modulo isomorphisms" so the statement that there are infinitely many is correct.

Comment: Reminds me of a (possibly apocryphal) story of a student's answer to the test question "Which of the following groups is isomorphic?" Answer: "(A) is isomorphic but (B) and (C) are not."

Answer (score 2):

Your question/answer and what you write at the bottom contradict one another. There are $3$ abelian groups of order $8$, up to isomorphism. And you've listed them:

$$\mathbb Z_8,\;\;\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2,\, \text{ or }\,\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2.$$

Among those three groups, no two of them is isomorphic. So it is false any two abelian groups of order $8$ are isomporphic.

$$\begin{align}\mathbb Z_8&\not\cong \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2& \mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2 &\not\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2&
\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2&\not\cong \mathbb Z_8 \end{align}$$

It *is* true that all abelian groups of order $8$ are isomorphic to one of the three non-isomorphic groups: $$\mathbb Z_8,\;\;\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2,\, \text{ or }\,\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2.$$